# Depth photo Lidar the photo is repeating the colors

Tags: swift, swiftui

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGm2x.png)I am new to swift development for 1 month. I need to save a picture using a lidar sensor from iOS and convert it to a depth photo. it works but the image is bad.IT repeats THE COLOR or something like this. I need to save it as an array float .. but I don't know how. Help, please.Thanks

I need to save it to r32f I think

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to show how you're converting the lidar depth value to a colour?